# How can I prove that any function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I have to find all functions of the type:

$$f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

that are continuous. My claim is that all such functions are continuous. If we think about it, $f$ would only have isolated points and we know that a function is always considered continuous at an isolated point. So, by this reasoning, any function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. I hope my reasoning is correct. What I am confused about is how could I prove this formally. We know that continuity is defined like this:

A function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $c \in A$ if

$$\forall V \in \mathcal{V}(f(c)), \exists U \in \mathcal{V}(c) \text{ such that } \forall x \in U \cap A \text{ we have } f(x) \in V$$

How could I possibly prove my point using the definition of continuity? It's really not that difficult to find the answer intuitively, but I don't see how I could make my argument more formal.

Comment: Bro... isolated points are _never_ continuous...

Comment: You need a topological definition of continuity. Then if $\mathbb N$ has the discrete topology, any function from $\mathbb N$ is continuous.

Comment: @SenZen You are incorrect. You have to respect the topology of $\mathbb{N}$, which is the discrete one. So every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is open. A function is continuous if the preimage of an open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open. But as every subset is open with regards to the discrete topology we have that $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is always open. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Wait what on earth is that definition of continuity? I know of the epsilon-delta definition, but I've never seen that one, and it makes no sense to me - what is $\mathcal{V}$??

Comment: Ah I think this should be tagged under topology then, not real analysis...

Comment: @SenZen $\mathcal{V}(c)$ is the set of all neighborhoods of the point $c$. Sorry if this definition doesn't make sense, but this is the one I was taught.

Comment: @SenZen Would it be easier to prove this if we were to use the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definition of continuity? We weren't told about it, but I'm willing to learn it if it will help me in this proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $c\in\Bbb N$, take $\mathcal V(c)=\{c\}$. You can do it, since it is a neighborhood of $c$.

Comment: But I don't think I can do that. At least the way I was taught, a neighborhood of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is an interval of the type $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. We were told that $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, but it can't really be $0$. So what should I do about that?

Comment: I am sorry, but that is **not** the definition of neighborhood. Or are you claiming that $(-1,2)$ is not a neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: Yes, it is a neighborhood according to that definition, but what you wrote was that a neighborhood of $x$ is an interval of the type $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$, and $(-1,2)$ is **not** an interval of the form $(0-\varepsilon,0+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Anyway, a neighborhood of a natural number $c$ in $\Bbb N$ is a set $V$ that contains $(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)\cap\Bbb N$, for some $\varepsilon>0$. So, $\{c\}$ **is** a neighborhood of $c$ in $\Bbb N$, since it is equal to $(c-1,c+1)\cap\Bbb N$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for putting up with me :)